# warning: passing argument 1 of 'HashInsertar' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, array, lista, hash

Tengo este programa que debería implementar una función de hasheo. Pero tira la siguiente advertencia que está más arriba:

> ```
> warning: passing argument 1 of 'HashInsertar' from incompatible pointer type
> ```

Cuando se le intenta pasar el número que ingresó el usuario a la función `HashInsertar` sale la advertencia de arriba y no se como corregirlo ¿que puedo hacer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define HASHMAX 10

typedef struct nodoL {
    int info;
    struct nodoL * sig;
    struct nodoL * ant;
} * lista;

// DEFINICIÓN DE LAS FUNCIONES
//************* HASH **********

typedef lista Hash[HASHMAX];
int HashClave(int n);
void HashInsertar(Hash *h, int e);
void HashMostrar(Hash h);
void HashBuscar(Hash h, int n);

//********  LISTA   *******
void enlistar (lista *L, int n);
int mostrar (lista L); /* muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva */
void borrar(lista *L, int n);

int HashClave (int n)
{
    return n%HASHMAX;
}

void HashInsertar (Hash *h, int e)
{
    enlistar ((h)[HashClave(e)],e);
}

void HashMostrar(Hash h)
{
    int i, n;
    for (n=0;n<HASHMAX;n++){
        printf("Hash [%d]: ",n);
        i=mostrar(h);
        if(i==0)printf("Lista  vacia \n\n");
        else printf("# \n\n");
    }
}

void enlistar (lista *L, int n)
{
    lista aux = (lista)malloc(sizeof(struct nodoL));
    if(*L==NULL){
        aux -> info = n;
        aux -> sig = *L;
        *L=aux;
    }
    else{
        if((*L)->info>n){
            aux -> info = n;
            aux -> sig = *L;
            *L=aux;
        }
        else{
            enlistar(&(*L)->sig,n);
        }
    }
}

int mostrar (lista L)
{
    int i=0;
    if(L!=NULL)
    {
        i=1;
        printf("[%d]->",L->info);
        mostrar(L->sig);
    }
    return i;
}


void borrar(lista *L, int n)
{
    lista aux = *L;
    lista ant = NULL;
    if(aux==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Lista vacia");
    }
    else
    {
        while (aux->info!=n&&aux->sig!=NULL)
        {
            ant=aux;
            aux=aux->sig;
        }
        if(aux->sig==NULL&&aux->info!=n)
               printf("Error, numero no se encuentra en la lista");
        else
        {
            ant->sig=aux->sig;
            free (aux);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int op=-1;
    int c;
    lista milista=NULL;
    do
    {
        while(op)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("\t\tEjemplo de Hash\n\n\t"
                   "Seleccione una opcion\n\n\t"
                   "-1. Agregar elemento a la lista\n\t"
                   "-2. Mostrar lista\n\t"
                   "-3. Borrar un elemento\n\t"
                   "-0. Salir\n");
            scanf("%d",&op);
            switch(op)
            {
            case 1:
            {
                int n, e;
                system("cls");
                printf("Ingrese la clave del hash para el elemento:\n");
                scanf("%d",&n);
                printf("Ingrese el numero para agregar a la lista:\n");
                scanf("%d",&e);
                system("cls");
                HashInsertar(&milista,e);//<-------LLamará al procedimiento que inserta un numero al hash.
                printf("%d se ha agregado con exito a la lista ", e);
                getch();
                break;
            }
            //Mostrar lista por pantalla.
            case 2:
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("Los numeros cargados en la lista:\n\n");
                HashMostrar(&milista);
                getch();
            }
            break;
            //Eliminar un número de la lista.
            case 3:
            {
                int n;
                system("cls");
                printf("Ingrese el numero para borrar de la lista:\n");
                scanf("%d",&n);
                system("cls");
                borrar(&milista,n);
                getch();
                break;
            }
            break;
            default:
            {
                printf("Ingreso invalido");
            }
            }
        }
    }
    while (c == 1);
    printf("Desea continuar? (para si presione 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has dado con un error recurrente en StackOverflow en Español motivado por la mal utilización de alias de tipos y por la mezcla de conceptos.

#### Los nodos no son listas.

En el código que has facilitado defines el objeto `struct nodoL` para acto seguido nombrar el puntero a este objeto como `lista`. Y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

Esta nomenclatura errónea hace que sea complicado razonar sobre el código y que éste sea difícil de seguir y depurar, ya que el alias no sólo oculta el tipo subyacente si no que además le otorga un significado semántico del que carece.

Así pues: `lista` no es una lista de elementos, es un puntero a un `struct nodoL`. Teniendo en cuenta los conceptos correctos, este otro alias:

```
typedef lista Hash[HASHMAX];
```

No hace que `Hash` sea una formación<sup>1</sup> de `HASHMAX` listas si no que es una formación de `HASHMAX` punteros a `struct nodoL`.

#### Las cosas por su nombre.

Si ahora nombramos las cosas por su nombre, veremos por qué estás recibiendo el error que describes, la función `HashInsertar`:

```
void HashInsertar(Hash *H, int e);
```

No es una función que recibe un puntero a `Hash` y un entero (`int`) si no que es una función que recibe un puntero a una formación de `HASHMAX` punteros a `struct nodoL`, en la llamada que te produce error:

```
HashInsertar(&milista,numNuevo);
```

Alimentas la función con la dirección de memoria de `milista`, que ha sido definida así:

```
lista milista=NULL;
```

La variable `milista` no es una lista de elementos si no que es un puntero a `struct nodoL`, aplicando el operador *dirección de* obtenemos un puntero a un puntero a `struct nodoL` mientras que `HashInsertar` espera un puntero a una formación de `HASHMAX` punteros a `struct nodoL`: claramente está recibiendo un dato diferente al que espera:

```
| SÍMBOLO  | DESCRIPCIÓN                                            | TIPO               |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| &milista | puntero a puntero a struct nodoL                       | nodoL**            |
| Hash *   | puntero a formación de HASHMAX punteros a struct nodoL | (nodoL*[HASHMAX])* |
```

#### Propuesta.

Para evitar estas confusiones, llama a las cosas por su nombre, creando tipos adicionales si es necesario:

```
typedef struct nodoL {
    int info;
    struct nodoL * sig;
} nodoL;

typedef struct lista {
    nodoL * raiz;
} lista;

typedef struct Hash {
    lista tabla[HASHMAX];
} Hash;
```

Con estos tipos claramente diferenciados, deberás hacer cambios en tu código:

```
void enlistar (lista *L, int n) {
    nodoL *punto_de_insercion = L -> raiz;

    if (punto_de_insercion) {
        while (punto_de_insercion -> sig) {
            punto_de_insercion = punto_de_insercion -> sig;
        }
        punto_de_insercion -> sig = (nodoL *)malloc(sizeof(nodoL));
        punto_de_insercion = punto_de_insercion -> sig;
    } else {
        punto_de_insercion = (nodoL *)malloc(sizeof(nodoL));
    }

    punto_de_insercion -> info = n;
    punto_de_insercion -> sig = NULL;
}

void HashInsertar (Hash *H, int e){
    enlistar ((H -> tabla[HashClave(e)], e);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que no he añadido ninguna rutina de inicialización ni liberación (y he escrito de memoria la rutina `enlistar` sin probarla), cada uno de los tipos requerirá ser inicializado y liberado, por ejemplo:

```
void crear_hash(Hash *H) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HASHMAX; ++i) {
        H -> tabla[i] = (lista *)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    }
}

void eliminar_hash(Hash *H) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HASHMAX; ++i) {
        eliminar_lista(H -> tabla[i]);
    }
}
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Bien, entendido, pero ¿el programa completo como sería?

Comment: El programa completo sería desarrollando lo que falta siguiendo la guía indicada 

Answer (score 2):

Francamente se me hace bastante lógico que te de ese warning, después de
todo la función HashInsertar tiene el siguiente prototipo:

```
void HashInsertar(Hash *H, int e);
```

Como primer argumento recibe un apuntador a Hash. Mientras tanto tu en el
main declaras la variable milista de la siguiente manera:

```
lista milista = NULL;
```

E intentas pasarla a la función hash:

```
HashInsertar(&milista, numNuevo);
```

Como antecedes el & a "milista", estás pasando un apuntador a lista a la
función, mientras que esta te sigue pidiendo un apuntador a Hash.

Vamos a expandir las definiciones de ambos para ver la diferencia:

Una lista está definida como:

```
typedef struct nodoL * lista;
```

es decir:

```
(lista) ≡ (struct nodoL *)
```

Por lo tanto un apuntador a lista sería un apuntador doble a struct nodoL:

```
(lista *) ≡ (struct nodoL **)
```

Mientras tanto un hash está definido como:

```
typedef lista hash[HASHMAX];
```

En otras palabras, se cumple lo siguiente:

```
(HASH) ≡ (lista [HASHMAX]) ≡ (struct nodoL * [HASHMAX])
```

Por lo que un apuntador a hash sería:

```
(HASH *) ≡ (lista * (*) [HASHMAX]) ≡ (struct nodoL * (*) [HASHMAX])
```

Entonces el apuntador a lista en comparación con el apuntador a Hash:

```
(struct nodoL **) ≠ (struct nodoL * (*) [HASHMAX])
        (lista *) ≠ (lista (*)[HASHMAX])
        (lista *) ≠ (Hash *)
```