# Programa de Hash en C

Tags: c, hash

Tengo este programa que pretende implementar una función hash en C. El programa compila bien. Ingreso elementos pero no quedan guardados en el arreglo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define HASHMAX 10

typedef struct nodoL {
    int info;
    struct nodoL * sig;
    struct nodoL * ant;
} nodo;

typedef nodo* lista;

// DEFINICIÓN DE LAS FUNCIONES
//************* HASH **********

typedef lista Hash[HASHMAX];
int HashClave(int n);
void HashInsertar(Hash *h, int e);
void HashMostrar(Hash h);
void HashBuscar(Hash h, int n);

//********  LISTA   *******
void enlistar (lista *L, int n);
int mostrar(lista L);/* muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva */
void borrar(lista *L, int n);

int HashClave (int n)
{
    return n%HASHMAX;
}

void HashInsertar (Hash *h, int e){
    enlistar ((h)[HashClave(e)],e);
}

void enlistar (lista *L, int n){
        lista aux = (lista)malloc(sizeof( struct nodoL ));
        if(*L==NULL){
           aux -> info = n;
           aux -> sig = *L;
           *L=aux;
      }
       else{
           if((*L)->info>n){// Para que quede ordenado
               aux -> info = n;
               aux -> sig = *L;
               *L=aux;
           }
           else{
               enlistar(&(*L)->sig,n);
           }
      }
}

int mostrar (lista L)
{
    int i=0;
    if(L!=NULL)
    {
        i=1;
        printf("[%d]->",L->info);
        mostrar(L->sig);
    }
    return i;
}

void HashMostrar(Hash h){
    int i, n;
    for (n=0;n<HASHMAX;n++){
        printf("Hash [%d]: ",n);
        i=mostrar(h[n]);
        if(i==0)printf("Lista  vacia \n\n");
        else printf("# \n\n");
    }
}

void borrar(lista *L, int n)
{
    lista aux = *L; //puntero auxiliar al primer nodo
    lista ant = NULL;
    if(aux==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Lista vacia");
    }
    else
    {
        while (aux->info!=n&&aux->sig!=NULL)
        {
            ant=aux;
            aux=aux->sig;
        }
        if(aux->sig==NULL&&aux->info!=n)
            printf("Error, numero no se encuentra en la lista");
        else
        {
            ant->sig=aux->sig;
            free (aux);   //elimino el nodo de la memoria
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Se declara y asigna una la variable para controlar la opción seleccionada en el menú.
    int op=-1;
    int i;
    //Se declara una variable milista de tipo lista.
    lista milista=NULL;
    //Se declara una variable h de tipo Hash
    Hash h;
    //Mientras op se distinto de 0 (Cuando es op=0 finaliza el programa.)
    while(op)
    {
        system("cls"); //Borrar la pantalla.
        //Mostrar en pantalla las opciones del menú.
        printf("\t\tEjemplo de Hash\n\n\tSeleccione una opcion\n\n\t-1. Agregar elemento al frente\n\t-2. Mostrar lista\n\t-3. Borrar un elemento\n\t-0. Salir\n");
        scanf("%d",&op); //Captura el numero opción seleccionada.
        switch(op) //Ir a la opción indicada por el usuario.
        {
            //Ingresar un valor al comienzo de la lista.
        case 1:
        {
            int e; //Se crea una variable para el número clave del número a insertar a la lista hash.
            int n; //Se crea una variable llamada n para el número a insertar en la lista.
            clrscr(); //Borrar la pantalla.
            printf("Ingrese la clave del hash para el elemento:\n");
            scanf("%d",&n); //Capturar el número que se indique como clave para el hash.
            printf("Ingrese el numero para agregar a la lista:\n");//Pedir por pantalla un número para insertar en la lista.
            scanf("%d",&e); //Capturar el número a insertar en la lista.
            HashInsertar(&h,e); //<-------LLamará al procedimiento que inserta un numero al hash.
            printf("%d se ha agregado con exito a la lista con la clave %d", e, n);
            getch(); //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            break;
        }
        //Mostrar lista por pantalla.
        case 2:
        {
            clrscr();//Borrar la pantalla.
            //Mostrar en pantalla un titulo.
            printf("Los numeros cargados en la lista:\n\n");
            //Declarar un variable y asignarle el valor devuelto por la función mostrar (0 Lista vacía 1 Lista no vacía).
            i = mostrar(milista);
            //Chequear si la lista esta vacía y mostrar en pantalla el texto que corresponda.
            if(i==0)
                printf("La lista esta vacia \n\n");
            else
                printf("# \n\n");
            //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            getch();
        }
        break;
        //Eliminar un número de la lista.
        case 3:
        {
            int n; //Crear un varible que almacene el número a borrar de la lista.
            clrscr(); //Borrar la pantalla.
            printf("Ingrese el numero para borrar de la lista:\n"); //Pedir por pantalla un nuúmero para borrar de la lista.
            scanf("%d",&n); //Capturar el número a borrar de la lista.
            system("cls"); //Borrar la pantalla.
            borrar(&milista,n); //LLamar a la función borrar.
            if(i==0)
                printf("Elemento borrado de la lista. Pulse cualquier tecla para regresar");
            getch(); //Esperar que el usuario presione una tecla.
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Son 170 líneas de código ¿No has podido acotar un poco más el problema? Te aconsejo que para la pregunta hagas una versión reducida del código y pruebes tu problema específico… es posible que llegues a la respuesta por tu cuenta si lo haces.

Comment: No tienen nada que ver la cantidad de líneas de código, estas ayudan a entender el programa, y pueden servir para entender mejor dónde está el error.

Comment: Si tienen que ver la cantidad de líneas de código, los códigos más cortos son más fáciles de analizar, comprender, depurar, mantener y desarrollar. Un código de 170 líneas, mal indentado, con nombres de variables confusos, alias de tipos no usados y ausencia de comentarios útiles es una pesadilla que no ayuda a entender el programa ni sirve para entender dónde está el error.

Comment: El error está en 2 de las 170 líneas. Puedes reproducir el mismo error en menos de 20 líneas. El resto del código es ruido.

Comment: Veo que no aplicaste los conocimientos adquiridos en [otra pregunta casi idéntica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192263/warning-passing-argument-1-of-hashinsertar-from-incompatible-pointer-type) que formulaste.

Comment: Y veo que [no es la primera vez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/287680/2742) que no aplicas los conocimientos adquiridos.

Comment: Está feo el código, pero lo que neceito que el código ande bien, por eso lo reposteo.

Comment: Para que el código ande bien, deberías empezar por aplicar los conocimientos adquiridos en preguntas anteriores, como [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/287680/2742) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192263/warning-passing-argument-1-of-hashinsertar-from-incompatible-pointer-type). Tu nueva pregunta no aplica NADA de lo mencionado en las otras preguntas casi idénticas que formulaste.

Comment: Vuelves a repostear y editar una y otra vez la misma pregunta sin apenas cambios ni aplicar las soluciones que te dan en las otras. Lee todas las respuestas que te han dado, intenta entenderlas y aplicarlas, pregunta las dudas que te surjan a partir de aplicar dichas respuestas y en definitiva intenta trabajar y limpiar tu código.

Comment: Estoy depurando un poco el código, ahora que el compilador anda un poco mejor y detecta errores que antes no detectaba.

Comment: Bien, pero en tus ultimas 5 ediciones apenas cambias 4 lineas de codigo en cada una(como mucho). Haz cambios sustanciales y cuando hayas avanzado de verdad, si sigues con errores, crea una pregunta nueva  centrandote en esos errores, en lugar de editar esta cada vez que cambias una mísera linea.

Comment: Porque seguis actualizando el codigo? donde esta la pregunta? porque cambias el codigo a cada rato? Si tenes otras preguntas, hacelas, pero deja de editar tu propia pregunta tantas veces, porque no vas a obtener respuestas.

Answer (score 5):

> Cuando le doy ejecutar aparece el menú, apretó Agregar elemento al frente y solo me deja ingresar un número y el programa no avanza.

Y para lo que tienes programado, es sorprendente que el programa llegue tan lejos. Tu código tiene [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) casi nada más empezar.

En primer lugar creas un objeto `lista` que igualas a `NULL`:

```
lista milista=NULL;
```

El tipo `lista` es un alias de otro tipo:

```
typedef nodoL* lista;
```

O sea que `lista` es un puntero a `nodoL`. Es una mala práctica esconder punteros en alias, porque da lugar a la confusa línea en que igualas a `NULL` algo que no parece un puntero.

Cuando intentas insertar un elemento en tu lista:

```
HashInsertar(&milista,numNuevo);
```

Le pasas la dirección de `milista`. Recordemos que `milista` es de tipo `nodoL*` (puntero a `nodoL`), por lo que `&milista` es de tipo `nodoL**` (puntero a puntero a `nodoL`), que casualmente<sup>1</sup> es `lista *` y es lo que la función `HashInsertar` espera:

```
void HashInsertar (lista *h, int e){
    enlistar (&(h)[HashClave(e)],e);
}
```

La función `HashInsertar` desplaza el puntero unas posiciones (tantas como devuelva la expresión `HashClave(e)`) y obtiene la dirección de dicho desplazamiento para llamar a `enlistar`. Y ahí empieza ya el desastre.

Recordemos que `h` apunta a `milista`, esa variable **no es una formación**<sup>2</sup>, por lo tanto hacer aritmética de punteros sobre ella es comportamiento indefinido; el comportamiento indefinido hace que el programa se comporte de manera errática (en este comportamiento errático se incluyen comportamientos que son aparentemente correctos).

Como solución, deberías declarar `milista` como formación:

```
lista milista[HASHMAX];
```

Y llamar a `HashInsertar` sin pedir la dirección de `milista`:

```
HashInsertar(milista,numNuevo);
```

Pero tu código es tan confuso y extraño que no se si te surgirán problemas adicionales.

---

<sup>1</sup>Si, casualmente. No da la sensación que haya una decisión consciente y meditada tras este tipado.

<sup>2</sup>También conocido como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.